# TabHost with different activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I'm trying to implement an activity which will include TabHost and each tab in it will run\represent a different Activity so if the user press on tab #1 he'll see Activity A and if he'll press on tab #2 he'll see Activity B.
I don't want to use TabActivity as it been deprecated but the new API FragmentTabHost just doesn't seem to be the right answer\implementation (i need to support OS 2.2 and later).
Does anyone have a good idea\example how to do it?

Thx

Comment: I want to clarify the scenario: i have an Activity which i would like to integrate in a Tab, so when the user press on a specific tab label the Activity will be shown and i don't want to use TabActivity for that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `TabHost` anymore. Use the new [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) API with [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). 
To support `Fragment`s down to Android 2.2 you have to use the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

Comment: Google use ActionBarSherlock as well, in, for example,  there I/O app. TabHost is deprecated. Your app won't be an success without using the new api and design guidelines.